# Create 3 classification models to predict the class based on the other available columns

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, prediction, modeling

I have three type of classes (stetosa, versicolor, virginica)  and also 4 other columns as sepal_length, sepal_width, petal_length, petal_width with around 150 rows and each it's filled with it's own information (so nothing is empty there). I need to predict the type of the class based on other columns.
This is what I have tried:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
X=df[["sepal_length","sepal_width","petal_length","petal_width"]]
y=df["class"]
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.1)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
clf=LinearRegression()
clf.fit(y_train, X_train)
clf.predict(y_test)
```

The text marked reponse with this problem:
    ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'virginica'
    I need to do this with train and test.

Comment: Why are you splitting your data into a test and a training group?

Comment: Split the data into train first to train your model and test it with data that model haven't seen before. It's a Machine Learning technique

Comment: Irrespectively of your error, please notice that you can not use a linear regression model for classification.

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode your data. in other words, transform each category in a number (int or float).

Map the following categories like this:

```
mapping={'setosa':0,'versicolor':1,'virginica':2}
y.map(mapping)
```

After you train your model, you will get `0,1 or 2` as a result. Convert it back and you'll have your predictions.

And by the way, if you are predicting a class, you must change your model. `LinearRegression()` is a numerical predictor it can only predict numerical values.

Try to use `SVC`, `LogisticRegression` or any other classification model instead.